# Animate text changes with offset simultaneously and fluidly in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Can I somehow achieve a fluid animation from one offset to another with the text changing? I know that it's possible using `matchedGeometryEffect` with two different buttons, but what if I have only a single one?

```swift
struct Button_Animation: View {

    @State var isEnabled = true
    @Namespace var namespace

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
                .ignoresSafeArea()

            VStack {
                Toggle("", isOn: $isEnabled)
                    .labelsHidden()

                Button(isEnabled ? "ENABLED" : "DISABLED", action: {})
                    .offset(y: isEnabled ? 200 : -200)
            }
        }
        .animation(.linear(duration: 1), value: isEnabled)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail? Is the gif what you want the end result to be? What do you mean by "fluid animation from one offset to another with the text changing?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with a single `Button` and `.matchedGeometryEffect`.  Switch to the `Button(action:label:)` version of `Button` so that you can explicitly use a `Text` to define the label.  Apply `.matchedGeometryEffect` to the `Text` and give it an `.id(isEnabled)` so that it gets a new identity when `isEnabled` changes.  Then SwiftUI will see the two `Text` views as different views and will be able to animate between them:

```
struct ContentView /* Button_Animation */: View {

    @State var isEnabled = true
    @Namespace var namespace

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
                .ignoresSafeArea()

            VStack {
                Toggle("", isOn: $isEnabled)
                    .labelsHidden()

                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text(isEnabled ? " ENABLED " : "DISABLED")
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 1, in: namespace)
                        .id(isEnabled)
                    }
                ).offset(y: isEnabled ? 200 : -200)
            }
        }
        .animation(.linear(duration: 1), value: isEnabled)
    }
}
```

---

[image: Demo running in simulator]